# Uncaught TypeError during ResizeObserver Call: chartObj.width is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, dc.js

I'm following [this example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web-src/resizing/resizing-scatter-flexbox-observer.html), using the following code

```
  // resizable chart function
  const callback = (chartObj: DCGraphicType) => () => {
    redrawChartNoTransitions(chartObj.width(null).rescale()); // @typeerror
  };

  // watch for resize and call callback when resize occurs
  React.useEffect(() => {
    new ResizeObserver(callback(chart)).observe(
      d3.select(div.current!).node()!
    );
  }, [chart]);
```

and getting this error:

```
ChartTemplate.tsx:77 Uncaught TypeError: chartObj.width is not a function
    at ResizeObserver.<anonymous> (ChartTemplate.tsx:77)
(anonymous) @ ChartTemplate.tsx:77
```

Note: the helper functions are

```
const restoreGetset = (property, value) => f => c => {
  if (Array.isArray(c)) c.forEach(restoreGetset(property, value)(f));
  else {
    const cs = c.children ? [c].concat(c.children()) : [c];
    const last = cs.map(c => c[property]());
    cs.forEach(ch => ch[property](value));
    f(c);
    cs.forEach(ch => ch[property](last));
  }
  return c;
};

// specifically, turn off transitions for a chart or charts
const noTransitions = restoreGetset("transitionDuration", 0);
// specifically, turn off transitions for a chart or charts and redraw
export const redrawChartNoTransitions = noTransitions(c => c.redraw());
```

This works on my local app (forced through the error), but I'd like to understand and get rid of it... Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-6ltfkk?file=utils%2Fdc-restore-transition-duration.js) with the error in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm haven't learned Hooks yet, so I'm not sure exactly where in React it's coming from, but it seems that `chart` is an empty object when the page is initializing, and becomes valid later.

In your `chartTemplate.tsx`:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    new ResizeObserver(callback(chart)).observe(
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
      d3.select(div.current!).node()!
    );
  }, [chart]);
```

It's probably not the right place to fix this, but ignoring the blank object:

```
if (!Object.keys(chart).length) return;
```

[gets it working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tpcfte?file=components%2Fdc%2FchartTemplate.tsx).

#### Debugging using Chrome DevTools

In Chrome DevTools, show the browser console and click on the code link in the error.

Set a breakpoint on the offending line inside the callback, and notice that `chart` is an empty object the first time the line is hit, but if you continue it becomes valid.

#### Debugging using `console.log()`

Adding, on the line before the error,

```
console.log(chartObj);
```

produces the following output in the browser debug console:

[image: debug output with trace]

The empty object is printed twice, each time followed by the error. Then the instantiated chart object is printed twice with no error.

Comment: thanks, that does the trick in my local implementation as well! Can I ask how you figured that out?... give a man a fish, feed him for day, teach a man to fish... :)

Comment: added debugging tips above. (deleting too-long comment ;)